# How to move images in kinetic?

Tags: kineticjs

I'm trying to move an image but I can't

```
...
  var imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {
        var yoda = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 200,
          y: 50,
          image: imageObj,
          width: 106,
          height: 118
        });
....
  // event button - move image;

  document.getElementById('show').addEventListener('click', function() {
      imageObj.move(0,5);               
  }, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few bugs:

- be be sure to draw the layer so your changes are displayed
- the element you want to move is yoda, not imageObj: yoda.move(0,5)
- the yoda object must be declared outside imageObj.onload so its in scope later

Here's code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/T2pfZ/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var yoda;


    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        yoda = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 200,
          y: 50,
          image: imageObj,
          width: 106,
          height: 118
        });
        layer.add(yoda);
        layer.draw();
    }
    imageObj.src="houseicon.png";

    document.getElementById('show').addEventListener('click', function() {
        yoda.move(0,5);               
        layer.draw();
    }, false);


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <button id="show">Move!</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't work  document.getElementById('show').addEventListener('click', function() {
              imageObj.move(10,10); 
                layer.draw();
        }, false);